# Uninstalled Compiz and OpenGL - Ubuntu won't load

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, opengl

About a week ago I installed CCSM and enabled wobbly windows. After using the `autoremove` command today, it was gone.  I decided that if I re-installed Compiz that maybe it would come back.  I un-installed Compiz and it's OpenGL window and compositing manager.  While those were being removed icons started disappearing, I restarted my computer after that. When the computer restarted, Ubuntu was stuck on it's loading screen with the dots.

I used the tty1 terminal to re-install Compiz, unity, and the ubuntu-desktop.  While doing this I got the `E: Failed to fetch` errors.  I've been trying for hours hopelessly reading other questions, but no luck.

Also, if I press the up button on the loading screen, this shows up with [OK] on the far end:
http://puu.sh/iedJV/fe737b9eb7.jpg

Comment: Not sure what you've expected. Compiz is the default window manager in Ubuntu, after all.

Comment: I'm still learning. Big mistake on my part I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the updatedb command as root first the perform the locate on the wpa_passphrase again

```
:~$ sudo updatedb

:~$ locate wpa_passphrase
```

if you still have the wpa_passphrase, try running the iwconfig command and see if your connected to a network.

```
:~$ iwconfig
```

the output should be something like this:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Your-Routers-name"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 84:24:8D:4E:75:00   
      Bit Rate=57.8 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:9  Invalid misc:15   Missed beacon:0
```

if your ESSID declares your routers name and you have a legitimate bit rate then run the following commands:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y &&  sudo apt-get -f install -y
```

and post the last 5 or 10 lines from the execution of the commands before control is returned back to prompt, like run the commands and what does it say at the bottom of the output. If it says

```
dpkg error sub-process [1]
```

than you have broken packages and I tell you how to track them, and remove them.

Comment: if you do, ill get you up and going again

Comment: Yeah, I do the `iwconfig` command, but it says I have no connection.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1700 EST: Yea sound like you had Network connectivity problems. After you run the updatedb command and verify that you have wpa_passphrase, and if indeed you do, check to see if you have your last network connection still located in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/The-name-of-your-router
```

If indeed you do have that file with your router address and encryption information, you need to get networking up and going. To do this gain root privileges and restart or possibly force-reload your network. For Example:

```
:~$ sudo bash
```

assuming your using a laptop with wifi (wlan0), as opposed to a hardwired ethernet cable for internet (eth0) you should relabel your essid

```
:~# iwconfig wlan0 essid "Your-Network"
```

Then restart your network

```
:~# /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Once you get back online run the

```
:~$ sudo apt-get -f install -y && sudo apt-get update
```

Then reinstall the ubuntu-desktop

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Let me know how it goes.

JUNE 13, 2015

Sorry ig,
I had looked at this post a couple of times during the week and I hadn't noticed your comment.

No you're not root. On linux systems (e.g. Ubuntu) there is only one root user who is the only member of group root. You gain super-user privileges with the sudo command, for example:

```
:~$ sudo bash 

:~# cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/your-routers-name > $HOME/your-routers-name.txt

:~# chown 1000:1000 your-routers-name.txt
```

Note: the previous command assumes your user and group id numbers are 1000:1000 respectively, your can test this by using the id command

```
:~$ id your-user-name

:~# exit
```

On Ubuntu, unlike just about all other Unix/Unix-like Operating Systems, there are certain features that are advantageous to gaining super-user privileges using fakeroot (sudo bash). One, which pertains to using the

```
:~$ cd
```

command (by itself when working out of your $HOME) while having temporary root privileges, which on most systems would enter you into /root; on Ubuntu it will simply take you into your $HOME dir. The other is being able to use the $HOME variable with temporary root privileges to work with files. If you are the login user of the initial session, the environment variables for the session apply to your interactions in the terminal while having temporary root privileges. e.g.

```
:~$ sudo bash
```

So just gain root privileges and then copy file with cat or the

```
:~# cp
```

command.

NOTE: Your only doing that to verify there is a file that has the same title as your routers name (your network access point).

I am so sorry I didnt get back with sooner.

Im gonna be on here on and off today. Post back

Comment: After I do the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/The-name-of-your-router` command it gives me a 'Permission Denied' message.  I am root.